# Vue delimiter not working in attribute, but working in element

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

delimiter is working in paragraph, but not working for image,
check below comments

```
<div id="productslist">
<div v-for="product in products">
    <h2>[[product.productname]]</h2>
    <p>[[product.mrp]]</p>
    <p>[[product.sp]]</p>
    <p>[[product.description]]</p>
    <div v-for="image in product.images">
        <!-- here delimiter is working -->
        <p>[[image]]</p>
        <!-- here delimiter is not working -->
        <img src="/media/[[image]]"></img>
    </div>
</div>
```

even in web inspector, this delimiter is showing as `[[image]]` only for image, but for paragraph `[[image]]` is being rendered

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't use delimiters in attributes.  You're also missing a binding on the `src` attribute like `:src` which is shorthand for `v-bind:src`.

Try using a string [template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals):

```html
<img :src="`/media/${image}`"></img>
```